# Firebase data retrieve with singlechildevent

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Here is my firebase data structure . The child "Tags" is a child of root.

```
final Query searchquery = mDatabase.child("Tags").orderByKey().limitToFirst(10).startAt(s.toString().toLowerCase()).endAt(s.toString().toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff");
searchquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        try {
            String u = dataSnapshot.child("article_name").getValue(String.class);
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,":/ : "+u.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception tg){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,tg.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I want to get the value of child "article_name" . I used the code above . But it is returning null .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference tagsRef = rootRef.child("Tags");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String article_name = ds.child("article_name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", tagsRef);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
tagsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
Blood Circulation
Dummy Article
```

Also don't forget to use names for the keys that does not contain any spaces. So you need to change `blood circulation` in `blood_circulation` or `bloodCirculation`

Comment: The reason you need the loop: when you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.